# SAS specific running of codes

Tags: sql, sas

i need to run specific codes in sas based on a certian if condition in Sas.
for example.

there's a code :

```
&Gender. = M

proc sql;
select * from test where loc="Florida";
quit;
```

i want to run the proc sql code only when the macro " &gender. " satisfies my condition of M i.e. if &gender. = M then run the proc sql part else skip the portion.

how is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by writing a small macro and then calling it:

```
%let Gender = M;

%macro gender_conditional_stuff;
    %if "&Gender" = "M" %then %do;
        proc sql;
        select * from test where loc="Florida";
        quit;
    %end;
%mend gender_conditional_stuff;

%gender_conditional_stuff;
```

The quotes around &Gender are not strictly necessary in the SAS macro language, but they prevent silly things happening if someone sets &Gender to a value that could be interpreted as SAS code.

Comment: No problem. Please consider upvoting and accepting this answer so that other users on the site can see that your question has been answered.

Comment: More properly you should use %STR rather than quotes; quotes can lead to as many problems as they can fix.  IE,  `%if %str(&gender)=%str(M)`.  Or, depending on potential responses, %superq or one oft he other sas quoting options.